# Network Partitioning

Tags: partitioning, consistency

My current understanding of the network-partitioning scenario, also mentioned in the CAP theorem, is that it's a scenario where the clients are not able to connect to some DB nodes even though they are up and running. For e.g. If a cluster consisted of say, 10 nodes, then it might happen due to some network issues that client A is able to connect to only 5 nodes, client B is able to connect to the other 5 nodes. In such scenarios, data inconsistency scenarios might arise and we need to plan for them.

As per my current understanding of partitioning, I don't see any such scenario arising when all the nodes are on the same rack/subnet. So this means that I don't have to plan for network-partitioning events(if I'm correct) as they can't arise.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct. We need at least two distinct subnet to talk about network partitioning.

But if your 10 nodes are in the same subnet, what is the point ? If your network is down, you loose your cluster !
Best practice would be to have 5 nodes in one datacenter, 5 nodes in another data center.